# how to optimize this helm template if else

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I need to reduce my 'if else code' in my helm chart template
How can I do that ?.

```
  {{- if .Values.global }}
    {{- if .Values.global.namespace }}
      namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }}
    {{- else }}
      namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- else }}
    namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  {{- end}}
  name: {{.Values.name}}
```

Comment: Would this work? `namespace: {{with .Values.global.namespace}}{{.}}{{else}}{{.Values.namespace}}{{end}}`

Comment: when global is null, this will not work

Comment: Then what about preprocessing the input assigning a `[]T{}` to a slice-typed field if it's `nil` before passing it to the template (with appropriate `T`)? Also note that you can register custom functions to a template and call them from it.

Answer (score 2):

"If `x` is truthy, then use its value, otherwise use `y`" is what the Helm (Sprig) [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) function does.  You could replace the inner conditional with

```yaml
namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace | default .Values.namespace }}
```

The outer conditional is trickier.  The problem you're trying to work around here is, if `.Values.global` isn't defined, it will evaluate to `nil`, and then `.Values.global.namespace` is an error.  The usual approach I use here is to again use `default` to get an empty dictionary if it isn't defined, at which point you can successfully do a lookup.

So you should be able to replace the entire block with

```yaml
{{- $global := .Values.global | default dict }}
namespace: {{ $global.namespace | default .Values.namespace }}
```

Comment: (The `helm install -n` namespace name will be in `.Release.Namespace` and this might be the best namespace name to use.  In fact, if you omit `metadata: { namespace: }` entirely, any object you create will be in the release namespace, and this might be the best and simplest approach, depending on what you're doing.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable and also `{{with}}` (which sets the dot), e.g.:

```
{{- $ns := .Values.namespace -}}
{{- with .Values.global }}{{ with.namespace }}{{ $ns = . }}{{end}{{ end -}}
namespace: {{ $ns }}
name: {{.Values.name}}
```